# Rails 4 + jQuery: PUT ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Ajax requests are still pretty new to me, but I have a recipe index with a button that allows you to favorite recipes.

```
<i class="favorite" data-recipe="<%= recipe.id %>">
```

... I am trying to use a PUT request to the route:

```
favorite_recipe PUT    /recipes/:id/favorite(.:format)    recipes#favorite
```

... using the following jQuery function:

```
    $(".favorite").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("favorited");
        var recipe_id = $(this).data("recipe");

        // displays properly when I console.log() it
        var url_path = '/recipes/' + recipe_id + '/favorite'


        $.ajax({
            url: url_path,
            type: 'PUT'
        })
    })
```

but in my developer console, I get a 404 error and the url shown is `Request URL:http://localhost:3000/recipes` rather than `http://localhost:3000/recipes/:recipe_id/favorite`.

**What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to use the data parameter to supply the id?**

Comment: As gil.neo said make sure you have the routes.rb with a route to this favorite.  Additionally, I believe you need a method in your recipes controller  with something like:  As gil.neo said make sure you have the routes.rb with a route to this favorite.  Additionally, I believe you need a method in your recipes controller  with something like:


`  def favourite
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @Recipe.increment!(:favourite)
  end `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm changing my answer because I noticed you DO have a route for that request.

I believe you're getting this error because you're not handling the request properly in your controller. Try to add the following to your controller, to make it handle JSON requests.

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render :json => {success: 'yes'}
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
$(".favorite").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("favorited");
    var recipe_id = $(this).data("recipe");

    // displays properly when I console.log() it
    var url_path = "<%= favorite_recipe_path %>"


    $.ajax({
        url: url_path,
        type: 'PUT',
        data : JSON.stringify({id: recipe_id}),
        dataType: "json",
    })
})
```

Comment: @Jeremy Thomas, try this/

Comment: @Jeremy Thoas, have you implemented this?

Comment: should the ajax be using method instead of type?

Comment: no ajax calls has `type` property for the HTTP methods.

Comment: no luck, might be worth noting in the developer tools I see the request for `http://localhost:3000/recipes` but under "initiator" it says `http://localhost:3000/recipes/:recipe_id/favorite`.  Also, your rails url helper isn't working because it requres an ID and I can't pass the JS variable to the rails url helper